# How to get the AppStore back on my iPad

Tags: ios-appstore

How do I get back my AppStore back on my mini iPad. Seems to have disappeared. Kindly help. I cannot see the icon and I can't find out how to install it back.

Comment: Have you tried using Spotlight search to see if it recognizes the app?

Answer (score 1):

You can't delete the AppStore App. I must have moved on another page or in a folder.

You can access it by searching from the spotlight search bar ! (slip down from the springboard)